# Android lint.xml doctype with dtd declaration

Tags: android, xml, doctype, dtd, lint

Is there a DTD resource for the schema of Android lint.xml files?

Right now I'm declaring a DOCTYPE without DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE lint>
<lint>
    <issue id="HardcodedText" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

This is working fine with and without the above DOCTYPE declaration. But I'd like to use the Android Studio XML code completion and would need a DTD url for that. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a DTD file, but Android Studio has been supporting this for a while now. It has some magic to work as if it had a schema.

Regardless if someone wants a DTD here's one
(comments are inferred by a quick read, hope I got it right):

```dtd
<!-- Based on com.android.tools.lint.client.api.DefaultConfiguration -->
<!DOCTYPE lint [
    <!-- note: not actually required to have lint as the root -->
    <!ELEMENT lint (issue*)>
    <!-- path to baseline file, absolute or relative to project dir -->
    <!ATTLIST lint baseline CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ELEMENT issue (ignore*)>
    <!-- comma separated list of Issue IDs, or "all" -->
    <!ATTLIST issue id CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST issue severity (ignore|error|fatal|informational|warning) #IMPLIED>
    <!-- note: not actually required to be called ignore, all element children of issue will be used -->
    <!ELEMENT ignore EMPTY>
    <!--
        No glob.
        string exactly matching project-relative path [platform dependent]
        string prefix for project-relative path [platform dependent] (e.g. subfolder)
        The following has to start with `res`:
        string exactly matching res folder-relative path [platform independent]
        string prefix for res folder-relative path [platform independent]
    -->
    <!ATTLIST ignore path CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!--
        regex matching the message (not whole),
        or regex matching the project-relative path (not whole)
        or regex matching the Unix-formatted project-relative path [on Windows] (not whole)
    -->
    <!ATTLIST ignore regexp CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```